# jsch configure session timeout idle

Tags: ssh, jsch

I want to setup session timeout idle , if the session is open I want to reuse it otherwise if it is idle for some time I want it to be closed automatically.  session.setTimeOut is not related to this at all , is there any way to configure timeout idle ?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl can I use ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax with jsch ?

Comment: Maybe `ServerAliveInterval=timeout` and `ServerAliveCountMax=0` can do what you need.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl exactly but how can I use them ?
   session.setConfig("ServerAliveInterval", "30");
                session.setConfig("ServerAliveCountMax", "0");
this didnt work

Comment: `Session.setServerAliveInterval(timeout)` and `Session.setServerAliveCountMax(0)`.

Comment: Strangely `session.setConfig("ServerAliveInterval", ...)` is possible, but `session.setConfig("ServerAliveCountMax", ...)` is not.

Comment: Thank you
Session.setServerAliveInterval(timeout) and Session.setServerAliveCountMax(0) it worked .  do you think its a bug  setConfig doesnt work?

Comment: It looks like an omission (what can be classified as a bug, depending on definition  of a bug).